# Reason for unwanted implicit reference to dll in c# project build

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a solution with quite a few projects in it and several dependencies to external DLLs. While trying to build a x64 version of the solution, I found that when building one project several libraries are copied into the output directory which are not mentioned in the project's references or anywhere else within the solution. I figured out that there is a collection of file names called `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal`, which contains these DLLs. In the concrete case the copied library was used indeed, but it is a x86 library, which overwrites the existing x64 file in the output folder. How does a DLL, which is not mentioned in any project of the solution, become part of this collection? Can some referenced DLL induce further implicit references? Can I control this behavior?

**Update:** In the x86 build the set of file names contained in `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal` is what I expected, namely one reference explicitly mentioned.